# Carrierwave with rails 4 strong parameters

Tags: carrierwave

I am  not able to upload image from carrierwave using rails 4 whitelistng

```
def create

      @product=Product.new(products_params)
       if @product.save
         format.html{redirect_to @product,notice:'Product was added successfully'}
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        flash[:error]=@product.errors.full_messages[0]
        render 'new'
      end
    end
private 

          def products_params

            params.fetch(:product,{}).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)

          end
    end
```

Comment: "image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb1edd80
     @content_type="image/png",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image]\"; filename=\"angular.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
     @original_filename="angular.png",
     @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151001-7062-1ft4vm4.png>>},      this is the params for image.

Comment: What kind of error your are fetching? Do you want uploaded image url form image?( `product.image.url` will return uploaded image url.) or you getting error when try to create product?